# Why is nan being added to data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I make an ajax call to a servlet which sends JSON data. I parse it with `JSON.parse()` and put it into a string to display in table tag in html. But with every row cell data it is showing `NaN`. I have checked the data there is no NaN.

Here's the code.

```js
var dataFromJSON = JSON.parse(result);
var count = dataFromJSON.count;
var str = "<table id='customers'><tr><th>LOGGED DATE</th></tr>";
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  str += "<tr><td>" + dataFromJSON.records[i].common.logged_date +
    +"</td>";
  str += "</tr>";
}
str += "</table>";
$("#data").html(str);
```

The data in `dataFromJSON.records[i].common.logged_date` is `2016-02-23 10:11:43`, but the table shows `2016-02-23 10:11:43NaN`.

Please help.

Comment: `NaN` = Not a Number. Somewhere a conversion fails.

Comment: NaN : Not a Number

Comment: You have one too many concat `+` operators.

Comment: yeah. that i know but where exactly. I am not converting anywhere. Just posting the data in  table

Comment: Thanks @BenFortune ...that was so childish on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
str += "<tr><td>" + dataFromJSON.records[i].common.logged_date+
                 + "</td>";
```

You have two `+` right after another. The browser tries to interpret this whitespace as a number

Remove one of the `+`.

Comment: Would whomever downvoted mind explaining what's wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You have put ++ please use only +

```
var dataFromJSON = JSON.parse(result);
var count = dataFromJSON.count;
var str = "<table id='customers'><tr><th>LOGGED DATE</th></tr>";
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  str += "<tr><td>" + dataFromJSON.records[i].common.logged_date +"</td>"; //chnage here
  str += "</tr>";
}
str += "</table>";
$("#data").html(str);
```